# How to know that my application is running in Background or Foreground?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, background, status

I am making Windows Mobile 6.5 Application using C sharp.

In the application, I am opening the default browser in a case. When I open the browser, the application is still runing in background. But I wish that the application is not runing and when the user returns to the application, the application is runing again.

So, I should know the status that the application is runing in background or in foreground.
How to know that???

If anyone knows that, please reply to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently you have 0 accepted answers from 13 asked questions. That is not nice. Mark good answers as accepted.

Comment: click on the grayed out checkmark next to the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemproperty.aspx

The property ActiveApplication

Will help you with what you want.

Also I found this video with Daniel Moth using the stuff above

http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/screencasts/screencast/191/Windows-Mobile-Managed-APIs-Status.aspx